# Get and set image size fail to work in safari

Tags: jquery, mobile

i have few big images on a page, thus when i do mobile web, i want to resize them when viewing for example on iphone.

thus i made codes like

```
<img src="http://www.wallsave.com/wallpapers/1920x1080/world-of-warcraft-cataclysm/443482/world-of-warcraft-cataclysm-games-trading-card-game-443482.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.wallsave.com/wallpapers/1920x1080/world-of-warcraft-cataclysm/443482/world-of-warcraft-cataclysm-games-trading-card-game-443482.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.wallsave.com/wallpapers/1920x1080/world-of-warcraft-cataclysm/443482/world-of-warcraft-cataclysm-games-trading-card-game-443482.jpg" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var w=$(window).width();

    $("img").each(function(){
        alert($(this).width());//shows 'zero'

        if($(this).width()>w){
            var nw=w-60;
            alert(nw);
            $(this).css('width',nw+"px");
            $(this).css('height','auto');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

the code is working fine on chrome on iphone, however when viewed in safari, no resize happens. Another weird thing is i try to alert the image size, but keep getting "zero" alerts.

Answer (score 0):

**you must call the function**

```
    <script src='jquery.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
              var w=$(window).width();

              $("img").each(function(){
                  alert($(this).width());//shows 'zero'

                  if($(this).width()>w){
                      var nw=w-60;
                      alert(nw);
                      $(this).css('width',nw+"px");
                      $(this).css('height','auto');
                  }
              });
           });

        </script>
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){` is exactly the same as `$(function(){` - that's not the problem.

Comment: I think that the problem is the version of jquery.. try to include jquery like this: `<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>`

Comment: sorry typo, the problem is not version of jquery. I have tried your method, But not working

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until the image is loaded, something like:

```
$("img").each(function(){
    $(this).load(function() {
        if($(this).width()>w){
            var nw=w-60;
            $(this).css('width',nw+"px");
            $(this).css('height','auto');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: When you add alerts, you see them all?